# undefined reference to `glfwInit' issue Clion OpenGL using cmake

Tags: c++, opengl, cmake, clion

I am trying to get an OpenGl project working on CLion. I am using 3 different libraries: GLEW, GLFW and SOIL.

The includes seem to work fine and everything get's found but every time I try to build I get errors:

```
undefined reference to `glfwInit'
undefined reference to `glfwWindowHint'
undefined reference to `glfwWindowHint'
undefined reference to `glfwWindowHint'
undefined reference to `glfwWindowHint'
undefined reference to `glfwCreateWindow'
...

C:/Users/John/OneDrive/OpenGL Projects/OpenGL/Lib_files/SOIL/lib/libSOIL.a(SOIL.o):SOIL.c:(.text+0x3e): undefined reference to `glGetString@4'
C:/Users/John/OneDrive/OpenGL Projects/OpenGL/Lib_files/SOIL/lib/libSOIL.a(SOIL.o):SOIL.c:(.text+0x72): undefined reference to `glGetString@4'
...
```

This is what I got in my cmake file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.6)
project(OpenGL)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp Shader.h Shader.cpp)

set(LIBS_DIR C:/Users/John/OneDrive/OpenGL\ Projects/OpenGL/Lib_files)

set(GLEW_ROOT_DIR ${LIBS_DIR}/GLEW )
set(GLFW_ROOT_DIR ${LIBS_DIR}/GLFW )
set(SOIL_ROOT_DIR ${LIBS_DIR}/SOIL )

set(GLEW_INCLUDE_DIRS ${GLEW_ROOT_DIR}/include)
set(GLFW_INCLUDE_DIRS ${GLFW_ROOT_DIR}/include)
set(SOIL_INCLUDE_DIRS ${SOIL_ROOT_DIR}/include)

set(GLEW_LIBRARY ${GLEW_ROOT_DIR}/lib/libglew32.a)
set(GLUT_LIBRARY ${GLFW_ROOT_DIR}/lib/libglfw3.a)
set(SOIL_LIBRARY ${SOIL_ROOT_DIR}/lib/libSOIL.a)


include_directories( ${GLEW_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${GLFW_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${SOIL_INCLUDE_DIRS})

add_executable(OpenGL ${SOURCE_FILES})

target_link_libraries(OpenGL libopengl32.a ${GLEW_LIBRARY} ${GLFW_LIBRARY} ${SOIL_LIBRARY})
```

Once I try to build I get a sea of "undefined reference" errors for GLFW and SOIL but not for GLEW.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You incorrectly set `GLUT_LIBRARY` variable to be pointed to `glfw` library, but linking uses variable `GLFW_LIBRARY`. As for undefined references to GL functions in SOIL library: **linking order has a sence**. Library-consumer should come *before* library-provider in `target_link_libraries` call. (There is definitely a question on SO which describes that, but I cannot find it.)

Answer (score 2):

I meet this problem as well, adding "glfw" at the end of the target_link_libraries() may help. I get this solution from reddit. https://www.reddit.com/r/GraphicsProgramming/comments/76rtt5/linking_glfw3_with_clion/

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues in your CMake file. First:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")
```

To ask for C++11, you may prefer setting [`CXX_STANDARD`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/CXX_STANDARD.html) on your target, or [`CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD.html) if you want to set it at global scope. [`CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED.html) can be used to make your wanted version a requirement:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
```

You should not call your executable `OpenGL` since it's ambiguous with the library.

To link against libraries, you should rely on [`find_package`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_package.html) to set the variable for each library:

```
find_package(GLEW REQUIRED)
```

Note that you didn't link against OpenGL, thus the undefined reference to `glGetString`. For the other undefined references, I guess your variables are set in a wrong way.

The correct configuration will be different for each package, but here is a cleaned version of your project:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.6)
project(MyOpenGLProject)

find_package(OpenGL REQUIRED)
find_package(GLEW REQUIRED)
find_package(GLFW REQUIRED)
find_package(SOIL REQUIRED)

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp Shader.h Shader.cpp)
add_executable(my_opengl_executable ${SOURCE_FILES})

target_link_libraries(my_opengl_executable ${OPENGL_LIBRARIES} GLEW::GLEW ${GLFW_LIBRARY} ${SOIL_LIBRARY})
target_include_directories(my_opengl_executable PUBLIC ${OPENGL_INCLUDE_DIR} ${GLFW_INCLUDE_DIR} ${SOIL_INCLUDE_DIR})

set_target_properties(my_opengl_executable PROPERTIES
    CXX_STANDARD 11
    CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON
)
```

Note that GLEW declares an [imported target](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-buildsystem.7.html#imported-targets) `GLEW::GLEW` which embeds include directories and other parameters: you just need to link against it using `taget_link_libraries`.

You will have to set hint variables for GLFW and SOIL for `find_package` to work. The variable names should be outputed in the error log when you try to configure the cleaned version above.

Comment: Because I am using windows I would need to use hints to specify the directories of the libraries?

Comment: Not for OpenGL and GLEW which should be installed in the directories of your compiler (MinGW ?). For GLFW and SOIL, I guess you may install them the same way, but if they are installed in an "arbitrary" directory, let's say in `C:/Users/John/OneDrive/OpenGL Projects/OpenGL/Lib_files`, you will have to tell CMake about this (you should avoid whitespaces in paths ; if you have whitespaces in a path, wrap it with quotes in the `set` command: `set(FOO "/path/with a/whitespace")`)